# MongoDb Docker polish characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, docker, microservices

I'm having problem while reading data from MongoDb using Docker (everything works fine when running it locally). For example I'm storing this object:
`("Szynka Tradycyjnie Wędzona", "Szynka wędzona to klasyczna polska tradycja.", "Sausage", 40.90m, true, null)` but when calling API endpoint, getting this:

```
"id": "64c056c84445ce6ff32e460b",
"name": "Szynka Tradycyjnie W�dzona",
"description": "Szynka w�dzona to klasyczna polska tradycja.",
"category": "Sausage",
"image": "product_image.jpg",
"price": {
  "amount": 40.90,
  "currency": "PLN",
  "unit": "kg"
  },
"isAvailable": true,
"isDiscounted": false,
"quantityModifier": {
  "isPcsAllowed": false,
  "kgPerPcs": null
  }
}
```

Why I'm getting � instead of polish characters? How can I solve it via docker-compose?

I've tried to set LC_ALL: C.UTF-8 in docker-compose, but it doesn't work. I think that I must set culture info in docker for mongodb, but don't know how. Also I've tried to just return string "ążśźćłóńę" form an endpoint and it works even if I was using Docker